# Establishing type introduced by a package(numpy) as one of the defined input parameters of a user-defined function in python

Tags: python, function, numpy, types

I'm trying to do a function in which one of the input parameters has to be of type numpy.matrix (which is defined in the numpy package). I defined it as it follows:

```
def MPC_controller(N: int, n_state: int, n_action: int, Q: numpy.matrix, R: numpy.matrix, A: numpy.matrix, B: numpy.matrix, x_ref: numpy.ndarray, u_ref: numpy.ndarray, action_limit: numpy.ndarray, state_limit: numpy.ndarray):
```

When I execute the file it always appear the same error, referred to the last parameter of the list of input parameters. I've been trying to do some changes, but I haven't been able to make it work.

Is there any special way of defining the type of the input parameters of a user-defined function when that type is one of the "original" types?

Comment: @Carcigenicate going to close the question, because I was searching for the error code in the error log, and it seems that the interpreter was the one of Python 2 and not Python 3, where the definition of the type of the input parameters of a function was established

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, if you are going to write a function establishing the types of the input parameters, always remember to use a python interpreter of a python version 3.X (and I guess that in the future >= 3.X), not 2.X.